# Revisit "What is the rank of $Q+Q^T-Q\circ I$ if $Q = qq^T$"

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

Based on my previous problem: [What is the rank of $Q+Q^T-Q\circ I$ if $Q = qq^T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997398/what-is-the-rank-of-qqt-q-circ-i-if-q-qqt)

1. $Q = qq^T$, $q\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $q^Tq=1$.
2. $A\circ B:$ Hadmard (elementwise) product
3. $Q\circ I$ just takes the diagonal entries of $Q$.

My question: Is $Q+Q^T-Q\circ I$ still positive semidefinite?

---

I guess the answer is not fixed by Gershgorin circle theory since the diagonal terms become small. Not sure if I am correct.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem statement is correct? If $Q=qq^T$, then $Q$ is symmetric and it is a bit weird to write the sum as $Q+Q^T-Q\circ I$ rather than $2Q-Q\circ I$.

Comment: @user1551 Both work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly not always positive semidefinite. E.g. when $q^T=(x,y)$, we have
$$
qq^T+qq^T-(qq^T)\circ I=\pmatrix{x^2&2xy\\ 2xy&y^2},
$$
whose determinant $-3x^2y^2$ is nonnegative only when $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: Well, then can I say it is negative semidefinite?  It looks like it is negative semidefinite for $n=2$.

Comment: @Denny No. In the example above, if $x\ne0$, the top left entry of $S=2qq^T-(qq^T)\circ I_2$ is positive and hence $S$ is not negative semidefinite.